# What does it mean for arithmetic truth to be definable in the language of set theory?

Tags: logic

Tarski famously proved arithmetic truth is not definable in the language of arithmetic. Ie there's no predicate $T$ such that $T(|\sigma|)$ is true in the standard model of arithmetic iff $\sigma$  is true in the standard model of arithmetic.

I have heard that nonetheless such a predicate exists in the language of ZF set theory. Since there is no standard model of ZF, what does it mean for an arithmetic truth predicate T to exist in the language of ZF?

Possibly “there is no standard model of ZF” betrays my total ignorance of set theory.

Comment: I presume there is enough explanation in [Hamkins' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273117/is-zfc-plus-a-truth-predicate-capable-of-variable-substitution-consistent) for this question.